# gdb: No symbol "i" in current context

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

While debugging a C program in gdb I have a breakpoint in a for loop. I cannot print the value of "i" ( I get : No symbol "i" in current context.). I can print the value of all the other variables. Is it normal?

Here is the loop:

```
for (i=0; i < datasize; i++){  
    if ( feature_mask[i] > 0 ){  
        k = feature_mask[i] - 1;  
        if (neighbors[k][nmax-1] != 0){
            neighbors[k][nmax-1] = bvalue;  
            feature_mask[i] = -feature_mask[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you're using the Bazel build system, here's my answer I just added: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386031/4561887.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It has probably been optimised out of your compiled code as you only  use `feature_mask[i]` within the loop.

Did you specify an optimization level when you called your compiler? If you were using gcc, then just omit any `-O` options and try again.

Answer (score 26):

I encountered this issue recently. I compiled GCC 5.1 and then used it to compile a C++11 codebase. And, although I could step through the program's code in gdb, I couldn't print the value of any variable, I kept getting “No symbol "xyz" in current context” errors, for *every* variable.

I was using gdb 7.4, but the latest version available at the time was 7.9. I downloaded the latest version of gdb and compiled it (using GCC 5.1) and when using gdb 7.9 I was able to successfully inspect variable values again.

I guess the debug information of GCC 5.1 is incompatible with gdb 7.4.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the program is compiled without optimization, and with debugging information enabled. It's quite likely that the loop counter ends up in a register.

Answer (score 2):

Check your optimization options. It's possible the GCC could replace the variable with a pointer into `feature_mask`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try declaring i as `volatile`. That will prevent some compiler optimizations (and hopefully make `i` visible inside the debugger).

Comment: This is daft. Don’t work round the optimisations – always compile without optimisations for debugging (except in the rare case that a bug only manifests with optimisations – but that’s another story).

Comment: To cut to your point though: you're saying that using the c compiler option `-O0` to turn off optimizations is better than making a variable `volatile` to keep it from being optimized out. Got it.

Comment: I didn't intend my use of the word "daft" to be as strong as "crazy" or "stupid", or even "foolish". It means something similar to those words, but it's more gentle and good-natured. Something like "silly".

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is using Google's [Bazel build system](https://bazel.build/) for your project, I'd like to add that if you cannot print *any* variables from `gdb`, it may be because you need to *properly* add the `-ggdb` and `-O0` (<s>update: [use `-Og` instead of `-O0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386189/whats-the-difference-between-a-compilers-o0-option-and-og-option/63386263#63386263)</s> use `-O0` over `-Og`) C build flags using the `--copt=` option, INSTEAD OF using the `--per_file_copt=` option. In my case, although they both built and ran just fine, only the `--copt=` technique allowed me to fully use gdb and print variables, whereas the `--per_file_copt=` one also allowed me to use gdb but would NOT allow me to print variables.

Note: in the below examples, just replace `test` with `build` if you do NOT need to run the unit tests as well.

<s>UDPATE: it turns out, you should prefer `-Og` over `-O0` when doing debugging, so I'm updating these examples accordingly.</s> See here: [What's the difference between a compiler's `-O0` option and `-Og` option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386189/whats-the-difference-between-a-compilers-o0-option-and-og-option/63386263#63386263).

**So, do this:**

```bash
time bazel test --copt=-ggdb --copt=-O0 \
//my/build/folder1/... //my/build/folder2/...
```

**INSTEAD OF this:**

```bash
time bazel test --per_file_copt=//my/build/folder1/...,//my/build/folder2/...@-ggdb,-O0 \
//my/build/folder1/... //my/build/folder2/...
```

**...in order to be able to print variables from within gdb.**

Again, *both* of the above techniques build and run just fine, and both allow me to run and use gdb, but *only the first one* actually allows me to use `gdb` *to its full extent*.

Lastly, if the first command above still doesn't work, try adding the `--strip=never` Bazel flag [described here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--strip) to prevent Bazel from ever stripping debugging information. Now the command will look like this:

```bash
time bazel test --copt=-ggdb --copt=-O0 --strip=never \
//my/build/folder1/... //my/build/folder2/...
```

## Reference documentation:

1. `--copt=`:

   1. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--copt
   2. [better, with examples] https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--copt
2. `--per_file_copt`:

   1. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--per_file_copt
   2. [better, with examples] https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--per_file_copt
3. `--strip=never`:

   1. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--strip
4. [my own Q&A] Prefer <s>`-Og` over `-O0`</s> `-O0` over `-Og` for debugging: [What's the difference between a compiler's `-O0` option and `-Og` option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386189/whats-the-difference-between-a-compilers-o0-option-and-og-option/63386263#63386263)