# What's the difference between a compiler's `-O0` option and `-Og` option?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, compiler-optimization

When I want to do debugging of C or C++ programs, I've been taught to use `-O0` to turn optimization OFF, and `-ggdb` to insert symbols into the executable which are optimized for using the GNU `gdb` debugger, which I use (or, you can use `-glldb` for LLVM/clang's `lldb` debugger, or just `-g` for general debugging symbols, but that won't be as good as `-ggdb` apparently...). However, I recently stumbled upon someone saying to use `-Og` (instead of `-O0`), and it caught me off-guard. Sure enough though, it's in `man gcc`!:

> `-Og` Optimize debugging experience.  `-Og` enables optimizations that do not interfere with debugging. It should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle,
> offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience.

So, what's the difference? Here's the `-O0` description from `man gcc`:

> `-O0` Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results.  This is the default.

`man gcc` clearly says `-Og` "should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle", though.

This makes it sound like `-O0` is truly "no optimizations", whereas `-Og` is "some optimizations on, but only those which don't interfere with debugging." Is this correct? So, which should I use, and why?

### Related:

1. related, but NOT a duplicate! (read it closely, it's not at all a duplicate): [What is the difference between -O0 ,-O1 and -g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663838/what-is-the-difference-between-o0-o1-and-g)
2. my answer on debugging `--copt=` settings to use with Bazel: [gdb: No symbol "i" in current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758614/gdb-no-symbol-i-in-current-context/63386031#63386031)

Comment: [The manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) has more details: `Like -O0, -Og completely disables a number of optimization passes so that individual options controlling them have no effect. Otherwise -Og enables all -O1 optimization flags except for those that may interfere with debugging:`. Then it lists the exact flags disabled.

Comment: Ah, that is useful! That's more information than is in `man gcc`!

Comment: If you read the excerpts in your question carefully, I think the answer is there quite explicitly. `-Og` optimizes the debugging experience, whereas `-O0` minimizes the compilation speed. You want to use `-Og` if you want to enjoy debugging, `-O0` if you want to quickly find out if the damn thing even compiles.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, true, but it's nice to have confirmation from other developers, especially when I'm so surprised by the new information (ie: that `-Og` even exists).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Quick summary

Do *not* use `-Og`. **`-Og` breaks debugging.**

Use `-ggdb -O0` (preferred if using the `gdb` debugger), or `-g3 -O0` instead.

Using `-g -O0` is okay too, but `-g` alone defaults to debug level 2 (`-g2`), which means that compared to `-g3`, `-g` is missing "extra information, such as all the macro definitions present in the program." (See `man gcc` and search for `-glevel`).

### Details

@kaylum just provided some great insight in their comment under my question! And the key part I really care about the most is this:

> [`-Og`] is a better choice than -O0 for producing debuggable code because some compiler passes that collect debug information are disabled at -O0.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options

<s>So, from now on I'm using `-Og` (NOT `-O0`) in addition to `-ggdb`.</s>

---

UDPATE 13 Aug. 2020:

**Heck with this! Nevermind. I'm sticking with `-O0`.**

With `-Og` I get `<optimized out>` and `Can't take address of "var" which isn't an lvalue.` errors all over the place! I can't print my variables or examine their memory anymore! Ex:

```
(gdb) print &angle
Can't take address of "angle" which isn't an lvalue.
(gdb) print angle_fixed_p
$6 = <optimized out>
```

With `-O0`, however, everything works fine!

```
(gdb) print angle
$7 = -1.34869879e+20
(gdb) print &angle
$8 = (float *) 0x7ffffffefbbc
(gdb) x angle
0x8000000000000000:     Cannot access memory at address 0x8000000000000000
(gdb) x &angle
0x7ffffffefbbc: 0xe0e9f642
```

**So, back to using `-O0` instead of `-Og` it is!**

### Related:

1. [they also recommend `-O0`, and I concur] [What does <value optimized out> mean in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497855/what-does-value-optimized-out-mean-in-gdb/5497906#5497906)

Comment: I also recommend `-O0` for debugging. With `-Og` breakpoints tend to trigger at wrong lines.

Comment: Yup, `-Og` code-gen is a lot more like `-O1` than the truly strict debug support you get with `-O0`. ([Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)).  `-Og` lets the compiler optimize away local temporaries.  You can see some of this with `gcc -Og -S -fverbose-asm`, that it's still inventing names for temporaries it invented, not using the original C var names, when operating on registers.  Although in simple cases it seems `-Og` looks a lot more like the C source than `-O1`: https://godbolt.org/z/zxcqb66jx

Comment: @GabrielStaples Have you retested this with the latest releasd gcc (v13.2.0 as of Jan 2024)? `-Og` seems to have improved debuggability and the aforesaid issue doesn't arise (in my trials). In that case, this answer perhaps warrants an update.

Comment: @DrKrishnakumarGopalakrishnan, I have not tried that version of GCC, no. If I ever do, I'll update the answer. For now I still recommend using `-ggdb -O0`. Thanks for letting me know you are seeing that `-Og` _is_ working now, however, in later versions. That's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the editing, the addition of `-ggdb` isn't entirely clear from [Gabriel's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386263/5012960) above.
I have found that if GDB is your preferred debugger, then along with `-O0` it is definitely advantageous to always also use `-ggdb3` (the `3` is important, better than just `ggdb`).