# How to link a dynamic library (.so file) with my C Program so that I can debug my C program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, makefile, dynamic-library

I have been provided a dynamic library (.so file) generated in the Linux platform. The file is compiled using the below command.

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic -o factorial.o factorial.c
gcc -shared -o libFactorial.so factorial.o
```

Now, I have written a C program to call some methods inside the library (.so file) and get the desired output. The dynamic library is kept in the same directory of my C program. I need to link the library with my C program at runtime so that I can debug my C program using Visual Studio Code.

```
Compiler: gcc
IDE: Visual Studio Code
Platform: Linux
C Program: my_C_Program.c
Dynamic Library : libFactorial.so
```

When I compile and run my code using the command prompt, I am able to call the methods inside the .so file.

**Commands**

```
gcc my_C_Program.c -ldl -o  my_C_Program   
./my_C_Program -l libFactorial
```

But when I debug my code using visual studio code, I am getting errors. Do  I need to link the library (statically probably ?) with my c program so that it recognizes my library. I don't know how to do that. Do I need to create a MakeFile? If yes, can you please advise how to link a library using that?

**Error while debugging:**

```
undefined reference to `dlerror.'
undefined reference to `dlsym.'
undefined reference to `dlerror.'
```

Please note that I don't have to generate the dynamic library. It is provided by others.

Comment: I think you may need to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Study this here: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html.

Comment: The library must be compiled with debug information `-g` which it isn't

Comment: Do you call dlopen/dlsym in your main program? Or perhaps they are necessary in the mathematical calculation performed by libFactorial.so?
Anyways, try this: `gcc -g my_C_Program.c -L. -lFactorial "-Wl,-rpath=${PWD}" -ldl -o  my_C_Program; ./my_C_Program`

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond, I do call dlopnen/ dlsym from my main program. The shared library has some function, lets say, func_1() that computes the factorial of a given number. The given number I provide from my main program. Now, when I compile the C program using the command line in the terminal of Visual Studio Code, I am able to call successfully the method inside the Shared Object (.so) and get the result. Now I need to debug the main C program. When I put breakpoint and press F5, I gets error that dlopen(), dlsym() are undefined. So, I need to configure VS Code so that it can debug my code.

Comment: @bolov, I tried with compiling with -g option and generated the .so file. The error still exists when I try to debug the code in VS Code.

Comment: Do you need to turn off optimization with `-O0` maybe, as I explain here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386263/4561887 Or maybe not--I think that is the default level if not specified.

Comment: The solution to my problem was simple but I could not find that so far. Thank you all for your valuable advice. I just had to add two-parameter into my task.jason file.                   "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                            
                "-ldl"             
            ],