# gcc 11 link error only when optimization disabled

Tags: ld, ubuntu-22.04, gcc11

I am facing this weird issue with `gcc 11.3.0`, a `-O3` build *works*, whereas when I build with `-O0 -g` (debug build), I get *linker error*:

```
/usr/bin/ld: path/to/mylib.a(my_file.cpp.2.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt6localeD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

From other answers on similar topic, I tried to add `-lstdc++` but that gave a lot
more errors! Is this a `C` vs `CPP` link issue ? If so, why do I see it only with `-O0` and not `-O3` ?

How to fix this ? (how to check which library the symbol is coming from?)

--
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mre] including all command lines to compile and link. Without these, we cannot help you.

Comment: Probably you don’t have a library (so or lib file) in a right path

Comment: Ok, After quite a lot of search, I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5556948/112687
the option `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files` worked for me, in addition to `-lstdc++`

Answer (score 0):

-o0 (setting optimizations level to zero) does not only mean disabling optimizations it also entails that debugging should work. Reference: [What's the difference between a compiler's `-O0` option and `-Og` option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386189/whats-the-difference-between-a-compilers-o0-option-and-og-option)

This means the reference symbols should resolve.

In case of optimized build that is automatically getting ignored however with -o0 that is becoming an issue so you need to explicitly ignore them using --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files switch.

Answer (score 0):

The library `.a` (`ar` archive) had all `C` objects but just 1 `.cpp`! So, I tried adding `-lstdc++` at link, but that pops up a lot of unresolved symbols.

Note: `-lstdc++` is same as linking using `g++` (instead of `gcc`)

The symbol is coming from some external library (most likely boost):

```
$ c++filt _ZNSt6localeD1Ev
std::locale::~locale()
```

Adding `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files` when the compile is done with `-O0` solves the problem (ignore if its coming from *regular object files*).